# Counting words in C

Tags: c, fgets, cpu-word

I'm trying to create a C code that uses the functions fgets(), strncmp() and strlen(), mainly to get a better understanding of them. The goal is to type in a text using fgets(), to shut it off with an end of file mark, and to count how many times a word (set in program arguments) occurs. This is what I got so far, but it's not working for me. I'm having a hard time using strings and arrays, as I'm a beginner C programmer.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, N, wrdcnt = 0;
    char buf[1026], *eof = "#EOF";

    N = strlen(argv[1]);

    while (strcmp(*buf, *eof) != 0)
    {
        fgets(buf, 1025, stdin);

        for (i = 0; i < (strlen(*buf) - N); i++)
        {
            if (strncmp(buf[i], argv[1], N) == 0)
            {
                wrdcnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", wrdcnt);

    return 0;
}
```

I could really use some help!

Comment: Check the return value from `fgets()`; it may fail before you read `#EOF`.  Also, `fgets()` includes the newline in the returned data; the chances are you'll never successfully compare the input with your `eof` string (because the input from will include a newline that you don't remove.

Comment: you;re using `strcmp` wrong

Answer (score 4):

First of all a general advice: Make use of the errors and warnings that your compiler is complaining about! You should be able to correct many basic mistakes this way. When compiling with `gcc` use the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` for extra warnings.

For example, you should get something like

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Indeed, the arguments of `strcmp` and `strlen` should be pointers to `char`. But at every argument that you pass to them (except for `argv[1]`) is of type `char` instead.

Using the `gcc` flags I mentioned, there should also be a

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

referring to the comparison `i < (strlen(*buf) - N)`. Indeed, the result of `strlen` is unsigned (of type `size_t`), and that could cause problems if its result was less than `N`. Their difference, instead of negative, would be considered an unsigned number, causing the index variable `i` to loop through a much greater range than what you intended, and possibly causing a segmentation fault. The solution is a cast: `i < ((int) strlen(*buf) - N)`.

Another bug is that the first time the while condition is checkced, `buffer` is uninitialized. Also, this condition doesn't look for an `EOF` mark, but for the 4-letter string `"#EOF"`. To check whether you have reached the end of file, you can use the return value of `fgets` instead. Even if you would like your program to stop upon the occurrence of the string `"#EOF"` on a new line, you should still consider that the buffer could contain `"#EOF\n"` instead.

A last issue concerns the "word recognition". Your current code, after debugging, would count an appearance of the word `"hi"` when it encounters the word `"hill"`. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: Granted. It was a conscious choice, due to the level of the question.